# Why does getting https://nytimes.com work but any particular article does not at all using requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get the contents of some pages from the NYT.

```py
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'}
url='https://www.nytimes.com'
response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response)
```

This gves me `<Response [200]>`

But if I change the `url` to any particular article for example - https://www.nytimes.com/2022/11/19/sports/soccer/world-cup-qatar-2022.html then it gives me `<Response [403]>`.

```py
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'}
url='https://www.nytimes.com/2022/11/19/sports/soccer/world-cup-qatar-2022.html'
response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Why is this happening? And how to make it work?

I also looked at the [robots.txt](https://www.nytimes.com/robots.txt) and I don't see any apparent problems.

Comment: You aren't authenticating, and that site has paid articles. You get a 403 on some of the responses if you try and visit the page normally as well. 403 seems like the wrong code for that, but that's not unheard of.

Comment: [HTTP403 forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) means the site will not authorize the request.  If the page you are requesting is only available to subscribers, you will need provide valid credentials with the request.